# Installed iOS 5.1 simulator, but it doesn't show up in list of schemes

Tags: xcode, simulator

I have XCode 4.4.1, which by default contains the iOS 6.0 simulator. However initially, I want to build some applications for iOS 5.1. I went to XCode->Preferences->Downloads and installed the iOS 5.1 simulator. But in my project (including projects I've created since then), the list of available Schemes contains only "iOS Device", "iPad 6.0 Simulator", and "iPhone 6.0 Simulator". How do I get the iPhone 5.1 simulator I downloaded to show up?

Answer (score 6):

Set the "iOS Deployment Target" in your build settings to 5.1 or 5.0.